# Skip arrays element having at least one empty value from specific elements in the loop

Tags: php, arrays

From a csv file i want to pull 2 columns having header `sku` and `images`. But i want to skip the rows where `sku` or `images` don't have a value or empty value. Here is my code:

```
$lines   = explode("\n", file_get_contents('../processed/MagentoExport.csv'));
$headers = str_getcsv(array_shift($lines));
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    foreach (str_getcsv($line) as $key => $field) {
        if ($headers[$key]['sku'] != '' || $headers[$key]['image'] != '') {
            if ($headers[$key] == 'sku') {
                echo str_replace(",", ";", $field).":";             
            }
            if ($headers[$key] == 'image') {
                echo str_replace(",", ";", $field)."<br>";
            }       
        }   
    }   
}
```

How can i skip rows having empty `image` cells? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems very confused. If I understand well what you are trying to do, I would write something like this:

```
if ( false === $handle = fopen('../processed/MagentoExport.csv', 'r') )
    throw new Exception('File open failed.');

$headers = fgetcsv($handle);

while ( false !== $fields = fgetcsv($handle) ) {
    $fields = array_combine($headers, $fields);

    if ( empty($fields['sku']) || empty($fields['image']) )
        continue;

    echo $fields['sku'], ':', $fields['image'], '<br>';
}

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: @MuntashirAreRahi: Strange! Use C multiline comments to find which line causes that.

Comment: Perfect! I made mistake on parenthesis. Now working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To skip printing you could do:

```
if ($headers[$key] == 'image') {
   if (!empty($field)) { 
        echo str_replace(",", ";", $field)."<br>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Its not skipping the whole row. its just skipping printing that cell.

Comment: No. its still the same as we are running if statement inside the cell.

Answer (score 0):

why you have two times the same conditions in your test

```
if ($headers[$key]['sku'] != '' || $headers[$key]['sku'] != '')
```

replace by

```
if ($headers[$key]['sku'] != '' || $headers[$key]['image'] != '')
```

Comment: My mistake. Updated the question.